# Reading and writing excel sheet using java apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am reading excel sheet using java apache POI. After reading i want to write on the same row, The ode is reading perfectly but not writing I want to create 6th column in every row in each iteration....   here is the code

```
 /**
 * Created by Muhammad Hussain on 26/10/2016.
 */
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * A dirty simple program that reads an Excel file.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class ReadExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\Muhammad Hussain\\Desktop\\Data-Collection.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(4);
        Scanner input =new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int rowIndex = 1; rowIndex <= 5; rowIndex++) {

            Row row = firstSheet.getRow(rowIndex);
            Cell cell = row.getCell(3);
            String review = cell.getStringCellValue();
            System.out.println(review);
            String label =input.next();
            row.createCell(6).setCellValue(label);

        }

        inputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you never write the workbook. So all the changes you make stay in memory. https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#write(java.io.OutputStream)

Answer (score 0):

You are only reading the file and not writing it. You have to put something like this in the end:

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("..."));
workbook.write(out);
out.close();
```

Comment: And note that you should write to a different file as in-place write is not (yet) fully supported.